# PHP connection using HttpWebRequest and Get method

Tags: vb.net, web-scraping

I have a script returns a string:

```
http://example.com/script.php
```

PHP script:

```
$data = $_GET['q'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE ID = '$data'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

print $num;
```

I want to connect this script with VB, using this code

```
Dim con As String
con = "http://example.com/script.php?q=" & My.Settings.setq

Dim request = HttpWebRequest.Create(con)
request.Method = "GET"
Dim response = request.GetResponse()
Using reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
   msgbox(reader.ReadToEnd())
End Using
```

It is not working.  How can i do that?

EDIT: I found solution

here

```
Dim uri As New Uri("http://example.com")
        Dim data As String = "data"
        If (uri.Scheme = uri.UriSchemeHttp) Then
  Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri)
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post
            request.ContentLength = data.Length
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

            Dim writer As New StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())
            writer.Write(data)
            writer.Close()

            Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
            Dim reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            Dim tmp As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
            response.Close()
```

Comment: Maybe you should give more detail. In what way does it not work?

Comment: when i run the script on browser i get the result (print $num), but in VB i get nothing, just an empty msgbox, i dunno really i just learnt that HttpWebRequest thats way i am asking

Comment: You made this way too hard on yourself: system.net.webclient would have done it one line.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Using wc As New System.Net.WebClient()
    MsgBox(wc.DownloadString(String.Format("http://example.com/script.php?q={0}", My.Settings.setq)))
End Using
```